# SQL transactions / error handling / updates

Tags: sql, transactions

I have a bit of a complex question. I have a stored procedure that takes no parameters.  Currently when I run it I get an error message telling me that

> *after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT
>   statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.*

In essense the stored procedure looks something like this:

```
    USE FirstDatabase
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [schema].[Procedure]
    AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    BEGIN TRY

DECLARE @WholeBunchOfVariables varchar(max); --All these are ofcourse separated and different data types

IF(SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tempTable
END

CREATE TABLE #tempTable (
    ...,  --bunch of fields to be populated
    IsProcessed bit) -- this field is used later to run through a temp table variable one record at a time, once done, this is set to 1

DECLARE @tempTableVar TABLE (
    ...)

    --Insert data from the accounts table(s) into the temp table.  Only process data
    --that has been modified in the past day.

    INSERT INTO #tempTable
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ... -- bunch of fields from different tables
    FROM
        SomeTables

    --Loop through the data in the temp table, one record at a time.  Process it and 
    --once done, set the IsProcessed field in the temp table to 1 so that it can pick 
    --up the next record to process.

    WHILE (1=1)
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @tempTableVar
SELECT TOP 1
    ... --bunch of fields from temp table
FROM
    #tempTable
WHERE
    IsProcessed = 0  -- check for first unprocessed record

    --The following variables need to be initiated so that it can be used for executing 
    --The main stored procedure that popuplates the marketing tables.

    SELECT
        ... --bunch of variables initiated from the temp table variable
    FROM
        @tempTableVar

    BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tempTableVar) = 0
    BEGIN
            BREAK;
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END

    --Another stored procedure is called here to be executed with the variables that 
    --were initiated a bit further up, as input parameters.


    EXEC [SomeDatabase].[Schema].[SomeOtherStoredProcedure]
        ... --bunch of input parameters / variables

COMMIT TRANSACTION

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

IF (XACT_STATE() <> 0)
ROLLBACK TRAN;

SELECT 
        @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
    @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
    @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-');

SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() +  '(Error %d, Level %d, State %d, Procedure %s, Line %d).'

    --Errors on this level, essentially raised by the secondary stored procedure, are
    --stored in an error logging table for later reference

    INSERT INTO [schema].[ImportErrors] (
        ErrorType,
        ErrorMessaae) VALUES (
        'Some Type',
        @ErrorMessage);

UPDATE
    #tempTable
SET
    IsProcessed = 1
WHERE
    someField = @someVariable ...

DELETE
FROM
    @tempTableVar

    END CATCH

    --Update the temp table's IsProcessed field to 1 for the affected record, if there 
    --are no errors.

    UPDATE #tempTable
    SET
        IsProcessed = 1
    WHERE
        someField = @someVariable ...

    --Delete the entry from the temp table variable so that it can be used for the next
    --record.

    DELETE
    FROM
        @tempTableVar

    END

    IF(SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable')) IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #tempTable
    END

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        IF (XACT_STATE() <> 0)
            ROLLBACK TRAN;

        -- Do the error handling.
        -- Assign variables to error-handling functions that 
        -- capture information for RAISERROR.
        SELECT 
            @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
            @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
            @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-');

        -- Building the message string that will contain original
        -- error information.
        SELECT @ErrorMessage =
    'Message: '+ ERROR_MESSAGE() + N' (Error %d, Level %d, State %d, Procedure %s, Line %d).';

--SELECT @ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage + @CustomerCategoryID + ' ' + @CustomerID + ' ' + @EmailAddress

-- Raise an error: msg_str parameter of RAISERROR will contain
-- the original error information.
RAISERROR (
    @ErrorMessage, 
    @ErrorSeverity, 
    1,
    @ErrorNumber,    -- parameter: original error number.
    @ErrorSeverity,  -- parameter: original error severity.
    @ErrorState,     -- parameter: original error state.
    @ErrorProcedure, -- parameter: original error procedure name.
    @ErrorLine);       -- parameter: original error line number.

    END CATCH
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming this is SQL Server? Please always include the tags for the specific RDBMS (and version) if appropriate as well as the more generic SQL or TSQL / PLSQL etc; there is almost always something DBMS specific that can help.

Comment: Secondly, that's rather a lot of code. Is there anyway you can condense it to something shorter and more understandable that equally highlights your problem. In doing so you might be able to solve the problem yourself; it also means that people are more likely to be able to help and it makes it easier for them do so.

Comment: I need to get data from one DB (several tables) and update another DB (several table) with the relevant data.  The secondary sproc does some checks and if there are errors I need to capture it into an error table.  While this is happening I need to keep processing, i.e. if one record has an invalid telephone number, I still need to run through the rest after logging this one to the error table.  I tried to condense it as much as possible.  Without having to email it to someone I don't know what else to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of code to parse - you have a lot of transaction start/ends in your code, and you have no checking before any of them to see if a transaction is still open or not prior to rolling back/committing.

Ideally you should have a single transaction commit/rollback statement for each logical set of inserts.

Comment: I'm going to try and redo it all.  I know somewhere my logic is just missing the plot altogether.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: Apologies - this isn't really an answer, but more of a guideline.